# Can I modify author when get patch from community?

Tags: open-source, git

We use GIT to maintain an open source code(GPLV2) for our Application. Sometimes we need to introduce patch from community when find bugs.

I wonder to know:

1. Can we modify the author when commit patch to our GIT repositories? We want to keep upstream info (author, URL, and patch's log) in commit info.
2. Do we need to distinguish this two scenes: patch has to be modified and patch has no modification?

Comment: "*Can we modify the author...*". Only if the author agrees, eg via you requiring patch contributors to sign a Contributor License Agreement (CLA) before you'll accept their contributions.

Comment: What are your policies and bylaws?  Under what terms do your users understand the patches would be submitted?  Do you frown on author comments like some open source groups (i.e. the code belongs to the project rather than individual contributors)?  There are certain clauses in your license which require attribution, but that can be at the project level rather than the individual level.  It's up to your project and the managing group to set those policies.

Comment: this doesn't appear to be a software engineering question.

Comment: @esoterik, see https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6311/3965.  This question is about git the workflow and is therefore on topic here.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt I see how the questions mentioned in your link would be on-topic, I thought the scope if this was more how to use git, than using git in a wider context, but it is is close to the line.

Answer (score 4):

Git differentiates between committer and author for this very purpose.  You can specify the `--author` tag when committing to show the person who actually wrote the change, and it will still remember you as the person who actually committed it.  This allows you to give appropriate credit where credit is due.